# Username wrapping

Tags: feature-request, bug, display-names

Just observed that lengthy usernames are not being gracefully handled in the user id box [such as can be observed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15234521/1530938). And this is not a corner case. It's customary in certain south american cultures to form a name from names of a number of relatives. It'd be nice to either enforce a name maxlength or provide tooltips/hover info. This has been observed on Chrome, the latest build